# How do I test whether coefficients in different models are statistically different when grouping off DV

Tags: regression-coefficients, wald-test

I'm trying to see whether good players in chess (those with more than a 1250 Elo) are helped more by puzzles than bad players (those with less than a 750 Elo). Usually, the way I would do this is with an interaction term. However, in this case my DV (Elo, which is a measure of skill) is the thing I want to interact with the independent variables.

Below I have two models. One of them is with data for players with less than a 750 Elo and one is for players with more than a 1250 Elo. How do I tell whether the coefficient on something such as LifetimeLessons is different between the two models?

````
badplayermodel <- plm(PlayerELO600 ~ LifetimeLessons + LifetimePuzzles + 
                LifetimeAnalyzed600 + LifetimePlayed600 + Username, data = badplayerdf,
              index = c("Username","Date"), model = "within")

goodplayermodel <- plm(PlayerELO600 ~ LifetimeLessons + LifetimePuzzles + 
                         LifetimeAnalyzed600 + LifetimePlayed600 + Username, data = goodplayerdf,
                       index = c("Username","Date"), model = "within")
```
````

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried fitting a model to both datasets simultaneously? I think it will be difficult to compare the coefficients of two models that are not nested. Assuming you have a `good_player` and `bad_player` indicator variable, then you could fit

```
PlayerELO600 ~ good_player:LifetimeLessons +
               bad_player:LifetimeLessons +
               ...
```

and then you could do a t-test to see if the `good_player:LifetimeLessons` and `bad_player:LifetimeLessons` are equal. Note that this model obviously wouldn't work in a predictive setting though, because it assumes you know `good_player` etc. in advance. Another thing to consider is that better players may do more lessons than worse players, so you may want to also control for amount of time spent in lessons and/or add the good/bad player indicator to the model before drawing any conclusions